# best way to iterate list and nested list

Tags: list, loops, logic

the first list contains the category and the second list contains items to that category.

for example:

```
list1 = {"vehicle", "fruits", "mobile phone", etc.....}
list2 = {"vehicle"=>"toyota", "vehicle"=>"honda", "vehicle"=>"..", "fruits"=>"orange", "fruits"=>"apple", "fruits"=>"...", "mobile phone"=>"nokia", "mobile phone"=>"samsung", "mobile phone"=>"iphone", "mobile phone"=>"...."}
```

so if im to display it in this format:

```
Category 1
-items
-items
-items
-items

Category 2
-items
-items
-items
-items

Category 3
-items
-items
-items
-items

Category n
-items
-items
-items
-items
```

currently im looping through both lists, check if the items belonging to this lists and display it. is there a better way to display these items and category?? cos u see if i were to display these category separately, i will have to loop 3 times.

here is an example of what i mean.

```
<!--display vehicle-->
for a in list1:
  for b in list2:
   if a==vehicle && a == b.key:
     print(a)
     print(b.value)
   end if
  end for
end for

<!--display fruits-->
for a in list1:
  for b in list2:
   if a==fruits && a == b.key:
     print(a)
     print(b.value)
   end if
  end for
end for

<!--display mobile phone-->
for a in list1:
  for b in list2:
   if a==mobile phone && a == b.key:
     print(a)
     print(b.value)
   end if
  end for
end for
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in a specific language? Why do you loop through list1 at all? It doesn't contain anything that is not in list2. Is it because you are using a language that doesn't allow sorted list access?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a HashTable instead of the second list.

In that way, you will have a direct access to the category items, without searching for them.
That makes it 2 loops, which is actually 1 over all of the items in both containers

If you develop OOP, I would suggest using an object with a category and a list of items.
And just creating a list of these objects instead - one loop.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO simply removing the hardcoded value from inner test should solve your problem

```
<!--display joined -->
for a in list1:
  for b in list2:
   if a == b.key:
     print(a)
     print(b.value)
   end if
  end for
end for
```

that's all